# Can someone give examples of use case of the ordered-set functions in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I just read the documentation and in specific this [page](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-within-group/), but I can not figure out one example (for example use case of this functions in analytics) in which I will use this, please could you help me with this mind-stopper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the examples in [Michael Paquier's blog post](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-within-group/) you are referring to are not enough, there is [another one in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY income) FROM households;
```

With detailed explanation:

> There is a subclass of aggregate functions called *ordered-set
> aggregates* for which an *order_by_clause* is **required**, usually because
> the aggregate's computation is only sensible in terms of a specific
> ordering of its input rows. Typical examples of ordered-set aggregates
> include rank and percentile calculations. For an *ordered-set
> aggregate*, the *order_by_clause* is written inside `WITHIN GROUP (...)`,
> as shown in the final syntax alternative above. [...]

There is more, read the manual.

Still not enough? [Depesz also posted a detailed blog post.](https://www.depesz.com/2014/01/11/waiting-for-9-4-support-ordered-set-within-group-aggregates/)

Comment: The last link has some good examples.  Thank you. (The documentation and the other link I posted, had examples but didn't show a use case as the link you suggested ).