# How do I pivot columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table with two columns: `care_team` and `city`:

[image]

I am trying to pivot these columns so that there is 1 row, and four additional columns. It should look something like this:

[image]

This might be super simple but I am in need of help.

Comment: You never added the code you tried, so I trimmed that dangling remark. Also, for your next question, please remember to disclose your version of Postgres and a proper table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script). And show data as text, never as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `crosstab()`

You can pivot with the `crosstab()` function provided by the additional module `tablefunc`.

There is fineprint to this, but your question is light on details. In particular, why are your cities ordered the way they are in the result. I assume sorted alphabetically. And I assume there are always 4 cities per team. Else you may need to do more.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT care_team, 1, city
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY care_team, city'  -- needs to be "ORDER BY 1,2" here
   ) AS ct ("Team" text, "1" text, "2"  text, "3" text, "4" text);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xolq57lf)

In-depth instructions here:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
- [Sum by month and put months as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598112/sum-by-month-and-put-months-as-columns/16598510#16598510)

#### Conditional aggregates

One alternative would be with conditional aggregates. That works with standard SQL features, but `crosstab()` is typically faster.

The specific difficulty of your rump case is that there is no "category" column. So we would have to create one in a subquery, for instance with `row_number()`. But, based on the same assumptions as above, we can make it work on a single query level with the ordered-set aggregate function [`percentile_disc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT care_team AS "Team"
     , percentile_disc (0) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city)
     , percentile_disc (.251) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city)
     , percentile_disc (.501) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city)
     , percentile_disc (.751) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city)
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xolq57lf)

Assuming 4 cities per team, each next value kicks in after an increment of 1/4 ...

See:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)
- [How to aggregate percentile_disc() function over date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781452/how-to-aggregate-percentile-disc-function-over-date-time/67781494#67781494)
- [Can someone give examples of use case of the ordered-set functions in PostgreSQL 9.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247036/can-someone-give-examples-of-use-case-of-the-ordered-set-functions-in-postgresql/29248534#29248534)

#### Your hidden agenda

You later commented:

> ... two columns, one column being the team and the other, a string value comprised of all the cities within that team.

That's actually a lot simpler:

```sql
SELECT care_team AS "Team", string_agg(city, ', ') AS cities
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6gPAuPS-)

See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

Comment: To add a little more to this, the cities assigned to the teams can change and the number of cities can change as well and are not always limited to just 4 per team. Some can have 1 and others can have 8 etc. Once pivoted the end result i am desiring is two columns, one column being the team and the other, a string value comprised of all the cities within that team.

Comment: @airking94: You should have said so right away. See added solution.